# IE11 crashes in a Kendo / JavaScript based web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11, mshtml

I have a ASP.NET MVC application based on Kendo UI and jQuery which makes IE11 crash after few moments of use. It doesn't seem to be in specific places, that varies and it doesn't show a pattern much clearly. What I did find is it's related to Kendo UI, jQuery and ultimately JavaScript, apparently. I couldn't do much troubleshooting since it freezes.

I tried all sorts of things such as clearing cache, disabling and removing add-ons, removing or adding KB's but had no success. This is logged every time IE11 crashes:

```
Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 11.0.9600.17496, time stamp: 0x546fddcc
Faulting module name: MSHTML.dll, version: 11.0.9600.17496, time stamp: 0x546ff2f9
Exception code: 0xc0000602
Fault offset: 0x00789403
Faulting process id: 0x3db4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d04548c07084c4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSHTML.dll
Report Id: ff908ef6-b13b-11e4-a246-b00594f250c9
```

I'm running IE11 on Windows 7 64bit SP1. I can reproduce the problem in every computer in the company.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What about error in console? Without seeing any specific code, it seems impossible to help you more. BTW, is it working as expected on all other modern browsers?

Comment: Does it error in FIreFox or Chrome?  Does it error in compatibility mode in IE 11?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it works fine in Chrome. I tried every emulation mode offered in IE11 and it crashes the same way. Curiously, it works in IE8. That's why I'm thinking it's got to be something related to IE11.

Comment: @A.Wolff, no problems shown in the console. It works on other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long period of investigation, tests and contact with Microsoft, they confirmed it's a bug with IE11.

It's not clear yet, but what is known is when the browser has to redraw tables and recalculate the layout and div scroll bars are present, it might crash. This didn't happen before and started happening after installing KB2987107.

So, the exit until this is fixed is not to use IE11 or use it without updating (bad).

Comment: we're also seeing this error - did Microsoft say they were going to fix this? or update you on this bug?

Comment: No @mh28. According to their support they have a long backlog for IE11 and couldn't guarantee anything. This is supposedly in their backlog, but will take long to be solved. Better to not expect it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the IE11 issue so I can keep checking for an update?

Comment: What is the current status?